# how to add space for drawing area in Line Chart

Tags: android

I am using [MPAndroid](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) Library

How can i add space between axis to draw the chart with spaces from left and right.
like I'm facing problem as shown in following images

This is my chart :
[image: This is my chart]
But i want my chart Like this:
[image: But i want my chart Like this]

Comment: i want space between the axis for the drawing area that is my line 0.5 in the SCREENSHOT should start with some Left margin.

Comment: check my answer and let me know it it helped, also check link

Comment: @MishaAkopov Your answer is not affecting the drawing Line i want the line  Drawing Line to start with some Left margin
please check the second  screenshot that i have shared now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not exactly what you want, but I think it is something similar and can be used
It has paddings from both sides, If the solution works for you, here is code

[image]

```
mChart.getAxisRight().setXOffset(30);
mChart.getAxisLeft().setXOffset(30);
mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);    
mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
```

Comment: I've updated code and added image, please see if it suits your needs

Comment: you saved my time

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue to resolve it add the following line:

```
mLineChart.setExtraOffsets(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Just set the float value for left margin, right margin, top margin & bottom margin and it should work like charm.

thanks.!

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have already used mChart.setExtraOffsets(10f, 10f, 10f, 10f); it gives margin from left and right to display Y axis of the chart..
but i want space between the axis for the drawing area that is my line 0.5 in the SCREENSHOT should start with some Left margin..